# JavaScript/jQuery weirdness concerning re-insertion of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a good sized script(200 lines or so) and I'm having problems with a seemingly trivial element of the code. I have a page and I am replacing the entire body with JS, however I need to re-attach a form so it can still be submitted after the page restructuring. (That submission will be triggered through JS.) However, what's happening is the code ceases to run following the `insertAfter()` call (Assumedly it's crashing within that function). As a result, the second alert and all subsequent code is not being run. Help!

```
var form = $("form").detach().hide();
$("body").html(newPage);
alert("HI");
form.insertAfter("#grades");
alert("HI2");
```

Note that `newPage` is a string.

Comment: Do you know how to use the JavaScript debugger in your favorite browser? Might be worth looking into that.

Comment: I haven't yet tried; I assume it'll be a mess going into the jQuery code.

Comment: Have you tried surrounding the `insertAfter()` line with a try/catch block?  The exception that gets thrown might give you some insight into the problem.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give it a try. (No pun intended.)

Comment: It's a `ReferenceError`. The error message is `Can't find variable: Menu`.

Comment: So based on the real code (not the shortened version) you have either a scope issue or something frustrating like missing brace or semicolon. ;-)

Comment: So how should I go about diagnosing the issue?

Comment: I think the diagnosis is in place; the question is how to fix it! Use an IDE or JSLint to help you see if it's a missing brace/semicolon (I'm guessing not--but that's just a guess), and if it's a scope issue you need to figure out how to get Menu into the same scope as the code that's trying to use it. I find using object literals for namespacing to be a cheap and easy way to avoid conflicts and manage scope.

Comment: @GregPettit Yeah, it's not a syntax thing, I gave it a check in Eclipse. It would've been nice if it was that easy, though :). I've never used object literals in JS, but that does seem like it would make things easier. The problem, however, is that the variable, `Menu`, is not mine, it's a part of a page I have no control over. I think instead of copying the form, I'll just watch the server query that the normal page makes and recreate it manually. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that the code as written has a problem. I wonder if in its shortened "easier to deal with on Stack Overflow" form it's missing the actual problem?

I fired it up in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cku9D/1/

(no real new code so I won't copy it here; if the fiddle goes down it doesn't really matter)

Seems to work.

Either something else other than the code sample is to blame, or it's something browser-specific. What OS and browser are you using?

Comment: It may be of note that this code is running in a Safari Extension, so it's cut off from the rest of the JS the page is using. Now, this is relevant because I'm messing with a large, complex, and awfully coded page (it's not mine). Could it be that it's trying to recreate that variable (Menu) and it's failing because it can't access the page's main JS?

Comment: Since your example here doesn't include the parts with "Menu" it's anybody's guess. Sounds like you have some pretty heavy sandboxing going on; scope issues wouldn't be a complete surprise.